# Currency Converter Not Converting

Tags: javascript

The Currency converter up top works, but the table based one is a dead duck.
I need a value to be entered at Enter Amount of US Dollars and to be displayed in the corresponding value fields.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Convert US Dollars to Euros 2</title>
    </head>
<body>
<form>
<table border="1">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Monetary Exchange Rates
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Currency
    </th>
    <th>Rate
    </th>
    <th>Value
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>British Pound
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" style="text-align: right;" &#010;name="bp" value="0.62905" size="12" disabled="true" />
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="BP" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Canadian Dollar
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" style="text-align: right;" &#010;name="cd" value="0.98928" size="12" disabled="true" />
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="CD" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Euro
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" style="text-align: right;" &#010;name="eu" value="0.79759" size="12" disabled="true" />
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="EU" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Japanese Yen
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" style="text-align: right;" &#010;name="jy" value="78.5461" size="12" disabled="true" />
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="JY" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mexican Peso
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" style="text-align: right;" &#010;name="mp" value="13.0729" size="12" disabled="true" />
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="MP" value="">        <!--&#010;td-->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><b>Enter Amount of U.S. Dollars</b>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" size="10" value="1" />
    </td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table> <br />
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate();">
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var BP = '0.62905';
      var CD = '0.98928';
      var EU = '0.79759';
      var JY = '78.5431';
      var MP = '13.0729';


      function calculate() {
          var amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount").value);
//            var e = document.getElementById("select");
          var select = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
          var select = document.getElementById("select");
          var result = document.getElementById("result");

          if(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value=="BP")

          if (select.value === "USD to EUR") {
              result.value = (amount * 0.7003).toFixed(2);
          }
          if (select.value === "EUR to USD") {
              result.value = (amount * 1.4283).toFixed(2);
          }
          if (select.value === "0.62905") {
              result.value = (amount * 0.62905).toFixed(2);
          }
      }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're using the id 'amount' at both the top and the bottom. Both buttons are triggering the same function. As a result, they're both reading from the top input and ignoring the bottom one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kamull61/dsQk4/

Comment: toFixed does rounding, though it's not as reliable as Math.round. In your example, though, I see only one place where it appears to fail - and it's actually a data issue. The conversion rate for yen is different between your script and your html. However, if you want to use it, you'd do something like:     document.getElementById("JY").value = (Math.round(amount * JY * 100)/100).toFixed(2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having dropped the select, the script you're looking for is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var BP = '0.62905';
var CD = '0.98928';
var EU = '0.79759';
var JY = '78.5431';
var MP = '13.0729';


function calculate() {
    var amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount").value);
    document.getElementById("BP").value = (amount * BP).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("CD").value = (amount * CD).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("EU").value = (amount * EU).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("JY").value = (amount * JY).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("MP").value = (amount * MP).toFixed(2);

}
</script>
```

We wouldn't want to list those out explicitly like that for anything large-scale; we'd build a list and iterate through it. But I think writing it out this way answers your immediate question better without muddying the waters for you.

Comment: Who's the man. S McCrohan is the man. Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 2):

`ID`'s should be unique, you cannot use same ID multiple times, and your select value does not work, change:

```
var select = document.getElementById("select");
```

to

```
var e = document.getElementById("select");
var select = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value=="your value")
```